# Babel doesn't ignore snapshot folder and files

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs, snapshot

I'm using the following npm build script with Babel 7;

```
"build": "rm -rf dist && babel src/lib --out-dir dist --copy-files --no-copy-ignored",
```

And this is my ignore section in my `.babelrc.json` file;

```
"ignore": [
  "**/__mocks__",
  "**/__snapshots__",
  "**/*.snap",
  "**/*.test.js"
]
```

Despite successfully being ignored matched `test.js` files and `__mocks__` folder, `__snapshots__` folder and files with `.snap` extension is not being ignored they're being copied to the `dist` folder.

Installed `devDependencies`;

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/cli": "^7.17.0",
  "@babel/core": "^7.17.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
  ...
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've wasted an inordinate amount of time on this. It is apparently a bug: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11394. File that are not considered compilable by babel are not ignored. There is a fix using the `--extension` flag that allows you to modify what files babel considers compilable.